# PayPal iOS sdk - Which calls should I make from Ruby sdk on my server after Single Payment from mobile?

Tags: ios, ruby, paypal, sdk

From mobile, I set intent to Sale and then sent the response to server. 
From server, I used Payment.find() to get payer-id and then tried to execute the payment using Payment.execute() but I get this error: PAYMENT_STATE_INVALID.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there was a confusion. When you set the intent to Sale and capture the payment from PayPal iOS sdk, the sdk does the execution for you. You don't have to do it again on your server. 
The only thing you need to do on your server is to verify the payment.